# Refactoring nested event listeners?

Tags: javascript, nested, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have this sort of quiz set up that goes through a series of questions that users answer yes or no. With each click, the next question replaces the innertext and depending on the answer, the user's "avatar" on the page moves across a certain distance.

Right now the only way I've gotten it to work is by nesting the event listeners and hard coding it, but I know that's not best practice and have been trying to refactor it without any luck.

Anyone have a better idea of how to achieve this?

```
const questions = [ "question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question 5"]
const text = document.querySelector('div.container')
const answer = document.querySelector("div.buttons")
const circle = document.querySelector("div.circle")

//questions will then begin
  
  const yesButton = document.querySelector("button.yes")
  const noButton = document.querySelector(".no")



answer.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (event.target.value == 1){
        circle.style.transform = ("translate(20px")
    }
    text.innerHTML = questions[0];
   

    
    answer.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (event.target.value == 1){
            
            circle.style.transform = ("translate(60px")
          
        }
        text.innerHTML = questions[1] 
        answer.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (event.target.value == 1){
                circle.style.transform = ("translate(100px")
             
            }
            text.innerHTML = questions[2] 
            answer.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if (event.target.value == 1){
                    circle.style.transform = ("translate(140px")
                  
                }
                text.innerHTML = questions[3] 
                answer.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    if (event.target.value == 1){
                        circle.style.transform = ("translate(180px")
                        
                    }
                    text.innerHTML = questions[4] 
                    answer.addEventListener("click", function(){
                        if (event.target.value == 1){
                            circle.style.transform = ("translate(220px")
                      
                    }
                    
                
                })
                })
                                    
        })
    }) }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const questions = [ "question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question 5"]
const text = document.querySelector('div.container')
const answer = document.querySelector("div.buttons")
const circle = document.querySelector("div.circle")

//questions will then begin
  
  const yesButton = document.querySelector("button.yes")
  const noButton = document.querySelector(".no")

var currentQuestion = 0;

answer.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (event.target.value == 1){
        circle.style.transform = ( window.getComputedStyle(circle, null).getPropertyValue("transform").replace("px", "") + 40 ) + "px"
    }

    if (currentQuestion <= questions.length) text.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestion++];
});
```

I think something like that

it set the transform of the circle to its value plus 40px and if the current question is below or equal questions length, it shows the question.

Please test it and say if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It does loop through the questions, but doesn't move the avatar across the page.